# Is it possible to import Ableton Live's sound libraries into Logic Pro?

Tags: logic-pro, ableton-live, samples, format, file-conversion

I own both Logic Pro X and Ableton Live 9.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use Live's sound packs/libraries in Logic.

I have been using Logic since it was available for Windows; so a very long time.  It's been the centerpiece of a pretty comprehensive studio with some high-end gear, and I've used it both for composing and for tracking/mixing full bands, with up to 32 simultaneous inputs of audio at a time.

I bought Live thinking the different views might be a good creative tool and incentive to switch, but after some use have found that I rarely use anything but the standard sequencer view.  From there, I found the built-in instruments/effects to be quite limited compared to what I'm used to, *personally*; though I do find to the interface to be pretty and intuitive.

Regardless, after a week or so of use, I went back to Logic, and have continued making music in it ever since.  In a way it was good, because I no longer have the "grass is greener" syndrome and I know what the other one is all about.  I tried for a while using ReWire to sync Live to Logic as a slave, with Logic as the host, and while this worked, it was cumbersome to synchronize project files, etc (if I forgot to save one in the slave, the whole effort was worthless).

Between all of this and the recent updates to Logic adding some new additional Live-like features, I've been more prolific in composing in recent weeks in Logic than before.

Thus, I'm uninstalling Live since I'm not using it.  I have an SSD primary hard drive, so space is at a premium.

However, one big component of Live was the stock sound libraries that came with it (Suite, in this case, which has the most sound packs).  There are some great sounds and loops (drum loops etc).  Some are instrument files, but others are simply samples.

I believe they all are in Ableton's file format.  But, for the samples especially, I believe this is just a wrapper for an aiff/wav file.

Is there any way to import these over to Logic?  Perhaps in the way of Apple Loops?  Or if not a clean import, is there a way to break them out of their shell, and convert them from the locked-in, Ableton format, to aiff files, for use with Logic or any other sequencer?  I did, after all, buy this sample library, and should be able to use it.  But having to slave Live to Logic just to use Simpler/Sampler for a sample seems superfluous and a drain on system resources.

Are there any tools, hacks, reverse engineering, command line commands, etc, that would help in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Try [dBpoweramp Music Converter](https://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm). That's what I've used for converting audio files. With the right codecs (which are free) you can pretty much convert anything to the extension you wish to use.

As for finding the files you want to extract from Ableton, just search around the Ableton folder on your hard drive manually. They should be in there.

Hit me back if this doesn't work, I have a friend who has done this exact procedure many times right in front of me. I'll give him a ring for you.